# mkdir fails with tilde on OS X in C?

Tags: c, macos, mkdir, errno

I'm porting a C library to OSX which haven't given me much of a headache until now. In the next function:

```
int createDirectory( char *directory ){

    int error;

    error = mkdir(directory, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH);

    if( error < 0 ){

        if( errno != EEXIST ){       

            return errno;                           
        }            
    }

    return error;        
}
```

No matter what `directory` is, `mkdir()` always fails with `EPERM` (Operation not permitted). I'm not sure if the xcode executable is sandboxed or if I'm missing something, but every path I pass to the function fails.

I've tried to mkdir from the terminal and the folders are created without a problem, so I'm not sure where the problem is. This function works fine in Linux and Solaris.

Example paths:

```
"~/Library/Application\\ Support/myApp"
"~/Desktop/myApp"
```

The first one is an actual example of a directory the library should create.

Comment: `~`-expansion is a shell thing. Try without that.

Comment: Get the contents of the `$HOME` environment variable and replace `~` with it.

Comment: `EPERM`? Really? This is interesting as this error code is not document for `mkdir()`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mkdir.2.html I would have expected `ENOENT`.

Comment: And you're supposed to use the API get the location of the directories and that will mean the app will work in both sandboxed and non-sandboxed "mode".

Comment: In addition to the `~`, the attempt to backslash-escape the space and then backslash-escape the backslash is wrong. The first is a shell thing and is not appropriate in a C program (unless formatting arguments to pass to a shell). A path with a space in it should just be written normally: `"/a/path/with some spaces/in/it"`.

Comment: according to the man page: "EPERM: The filesystem containing pathname does not support the creation
              of directories."
  There is also the probability that the permissions on the parent directory are not set to allow the program to create directories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OSX does not expand the `'~'` character as `bash` does (although it uses `bash`).

Given this program, running in `/tmp`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *given = "~/Library";
    char result[1024];
    char *s;
    mkdir("~", 0755);
    mkdir("~/Library", 0755);
    if ((s = realpath(given, result)) != 0) {
        printf ("%s\n", s);
    } else {
        perror("realpath");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get this result on OSX:

```
/private/tmp/~/Library
```

I get this result on Linux (Debian) as well as with Solaris 10:

```
/tmp/~/Library
```

As noted in *[Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes)*, this was originally a `csh` *shell* feature which `bash` [incorporated](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_2.html) long ago (citing a page from 1994).  It is not implemented in any of the given systems' runtime libraries.

Comment: Err .. and how would this answer the OP's question on `EPERM`?

Comment: The root cause of the problem is OP's misunderstanding of the problem - the `EPERM` is interesting, but not relevant to solving the problem.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was indeed the '~'. Neither of the other implementations used ~, but when I was writing the configuration file I messed up thinking I was talking to a shell terminal. Also, as @alk said, I still have no idea why I get EPERM and not ENOENT.