# Open an ofstream with tilde (~) in path name

Tags: c++, linux, ofstream, tilde-expansion

I have to open some file for writing, and its name contains the tilde sign (`~`). The following code fails to create the desired text file. If I replace the `~` with `/home/oren` then everything works fine.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

const std::string dirname  = "/home/oren/GIT/";
// const std::string dirname  = "~/GIT/";
const std::string filename = "someTextFile";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::ofstream log_file(dirname+filename+".txt");
    log_file << "lorem ipsum";
    log_file.close();
}
```

Is there any way to (easily) handle a file with `~` in its name?

Comment: As an addage to both answers that existed at the time I wrote this comment: Depending on where the path comes from (user input?), the program should possibly be aware of other variants of tilde expansion, like `~user` referring to the home directory of the given `user`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ paths beginning with ~](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33544123/608639), [mkdir fails with tilde on OS X in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30285051/608639), etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `~` shortcut in paths is not something magical at the filesystem level, opening `~/GIT` literally tries to access `~/GIT`, i.e: a file named `GIT` in the `~` directory. You can verify this by creating `~` and `GIT` first.

In the command line, `~` is typically resolved by your shell. e.g: in bash:

> ~ : The value of $HOME

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html

Therefore, to achieve the same effect, you have to query the `$HOME` envvar, and replace the usage of leading `~/` in the path:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
const char* home = getenv("HOME")
if (home) { /* replace ~/ with home */ }
```

In addition, on linux, the [wordexp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) function can be used to perform these replacements (~ to current user, ~other_user to home of other user)

Answer (score 5):

The tilde is part of the *shell* expansion, it's not something handled by the underlying operating system. You need to resolve it yourself.

One simple way is to replace *leading* `"~/"` with the contents of the environment variable `HOME` (if it exists).

Answer (score 2):

The tilde is expanded to the home directory by the shell. The iostreams don't use a shell, so you have to take care of the expansion for them. Tilde is a actually a valid character to use in a file name so without expansion, a file is created into a directory named `~` - which fails if the directory does not exist.

There is no standard way in C++ for shell expansions, nor a way to get the home directory, but there are several ways in POSIX systems:

`wordexp` is probably one of the most useful functions for this case. You can pass the path to the function and it will expand the tilde, as well as variables and braces. An example:

```
std::string full = dirname+filename+".txt"
wordexp_t p;
wordexp(full.c_str(), &p, 0);
std::string expanded = p.we_wordv[p.we_offs];
wordfree(&p);
std::ofstream log_file(expanded);
```

Other alternatives:

`getpwuid` gives you a structure with the home directory as a member. This can be used to get home directory of another user as well, in case that is needed.

`HOME` environment variable should also be available. It can be accessed with the standard `std::getenv`.